# Equivalent definition of Cohen-Macaulay Ring

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

We suppose all rings are commutative and unital. The most general defition for Cohen-Macaulayness goes as follows: A Noetherian local ring $R$ is $\textit{Cohen-Macaulay}$ if its depth is equal to its Krull dimenion. More generally  a ring is called Cohen–Macaulay if it is Noetherian and all of its localizations at prime ideals are Cohen–Macaulay.

In Richard Kane's 'Reflection Groups and Invariant Theory', the definition of Cohen-Macaulay is given as: Let $A$ be an algebra over $k$, the ring structure on $A$ is Cohen-Macaulay if there exists a polynomial subalgebra $k[a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n]$ such that $A$ is free and finite over $k[a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n]$, where $a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n \in A$, in algebraic terms we can choose elements $b_1,\ldots,b_m \in A$ such that $$A = \bigoplus_{i=1}^mk[a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n]b_i ,$$
then let $G$ be a finite group and $V$ be a linear representation of $G$, then the algebra of invariants $S(V^*)^G$ is Cohen-Macaulay, this is the Hochster-Roberts theorem. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hochster%E2%80%93Roberts_theorem

Can someone enlighten me as how these two definitions are equivalent?

Comment: Are Kane's algebras graded?

Comment: @AnginaSeng not it is not graded, but the algebra of invariants $S(V^*)^G$ is graded. I believe Kane requires $A$ to have an algebra structure is to have a field to work with, so we can get the polynomial algebra, like Noether normaliztion lemma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is given in the paper by Hochster and Roberts, https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82276959.pdf, page 14. And one must assume that the algebra $A$ is graded.